# How can I type "can't" without pressing SPACE on US International keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard

How can I type `can't` without pressing <kbd>space</kbd>? When I use MacOSX if I type <kbd>'</kbd> then <kbd>t</kbd> I get `'t`, but in Ubuntu I need to type <kbd>'</kbd> SPACE then <kbd>t</kbd>.

Is it possible to avoid typing the SPACE?

I am using English US, international with dead keys.

**EDIT1:**

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    intl,
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'apostrophe' `'` without space (this is also used as 'single quote'), but 'accent acute' and 'accent grave' need a space (or another character) to be printed, because they can be put on top of letters (not only as a separate character).

Examples: ` (accent grave), à, é

US keyboard:

[image]

Comment: But is possible to type `'t` just typing `'` + `t`?
Because I just can get that result typing `'` + SPACE + `t`.

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer. Use the key, that is marked with a red circle (when using an English US  keyboard).

Comment: @sudodus If you are using a US keyboard, you are right. But if you set it to 'US international with deadkeys' you'll see what Araki means. My keyboard is also set to US international (because I need é, è, ...) and I have to type an additional space to get a standalone "'".

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using the wrong key: Instead of <kbd>` ~</kbd> press <kbd>' "</kbd> (next to <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to get `'`.

[image: keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using **Canadian English layout instead** you get the best of both worlds. Makes sense when you think about it :)

You can do everything just like the american international except you don't have to press space for the apostrophe \o/